# Sudden error in ReadOGR() for a shapefile of UK postcode areas

Tags: r, plot, maps, shapefile, postal-code

I have been using readOGR() to load in a shapefile of UK postcodes by region (Areas), downloaded from this website : https://www.opendoorlogistics.com/downloads/

```
uk_maps <- readOGR(".", "Areas")
```

Which loaded in the .dbf, .fix, .prj, .shp, .shx files without any problem and I was able to plot the blank map of the UK. (notably a 124-row file documenting the broad region postcodes).

Then when I reset my code, as usual, to try out new flows, I now get the following error:

> Error in readOGR(".", "Areas") : no features found
> De plus : Warning message:
> In ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  :
> ogrInfo: all features NULL

And I have no idea why I get this because I haven't changed the files in any way. I've just tried to redownload the shapefiles from the website link above, put them in a new working directory, set it, and the same error happens.

What's going on?

Best,

Cameron

Comment: I am not getting the error. May be restarting R and setting directory could solve your problem.

Comment: I tried restarting R, as well as restarting my computer. The error still shows up. It's really strange given that it worked fine yesterday. And I haven't loaded any additional packages in my script, nor have I touched the files in the folders + I redownloaded the files from the website just this morning

Comment: Just in case that can help, here are all the packages I'm using:
````
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(gplots)
library(forcats)
library(Matrix)
library(sp)
library(spdep)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(mapproj)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(plotrix)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(classInt)
library(vioplot)
library(grDevices)
library(classInt)
library(data.table)
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG I think I solved the issue which was pretty stupid, don't know if this question should be deleted or left for Mac users.

Users of iCloud may know that iCloud sometimes randomly stores files in the Cloud to optimise storage, and when that's the case the file still appears in your directory but is actually not there (cloud sign next to the file).

[image]

In my case all of my .shp files where "clouded" (including District and Sectors) so I was mistakenly thinking there was an issue elsewhere

You have to really make sure none of your files are stored in the Cloud if you want R to read them properly.